# What is the common application of a Power Resistor Decade Box?

Tags: resistors

I recently found a Power Resistor Decade box at a thrift store.  It looked cool and was only 10$ so I figured what's to lose.

I understand what it does (allows you to specify any resistance in it's range), but I don't understand what it's commonly used for.

As a hobbyist who sometimes tinkers in electronics (I'm a software guy, so mainly microcontrollers), do I have any need for this?

[image]
([clarostat 240-c](http://www.bellnw.com/manufacturer/Clarostat/240-C.htm))

Also, I tested each of the individual setting (using this [multimeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M7ZD1VN)) and these are the results.

[image]
([google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmOhaCNXPFXUSdhzSQr0JQhCtwGScow5fgOfL2GL-8Q/edit?usp=sharing))

Are these variances standard or is this one broken? (I realise I shouldn't have converted but instead left it at actual measured precision)

Comment: There are std. values that depend on tolerance for 10%, 5% 2%,1% 0.1% etc.  Decade boxes are good for learning tools but tend to be poor in MHz range due to lead inductance. Often switches are break before make causing glitch that needs cap for filtering. But you can use it for trial and error... just dont apply power source across 1.4 ohms ;)  Often used in "Wheatstone bridge" designs to calibrate thermistors.

Comment: or a 6 decade mechanical DAC box (D to A converter with a reference Resistor and Vref in a divider circuit. But dont expect it to be monotonic from 9.9999 to 10.000

Comment: One use was in lab experiments to have an easy method of changing loads - usually specified as between X and Y as per Tony's comment about 1.4 ohms...

Comment: sounds like there is limited practical application for a hobbyist ;)

Comment: temporary testing to determine pot. range of useful speed control system or dimmer control

Comment: As for another use : if you do a classic Frankenstein sketch it would look great if the bulbs get brighter as you change the values... but make sure it is safe...

Comment: Depends on the accuracy and type of resistors. Can be for calibration, load testing, value twiddling etc.

Comment: Look up Wheatstone Bridge to see how it can measure unknown R values ( before the advent of DMM's)

Comment: Looks great on a glass shelf with a light on it ... nice find BTW

Comment: @tony all good boxes are make before break, especially when they are older and bigger. Nothing gets over my 0.01% Siemens decade from 1953..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a special one (in my opinion) as it is a power resistor decade. Having a look at the linked specification, it is able to dissipate 225 W. That is huge.

So I can imagine this thing being used as a means to test power supplies before electronic loads where used for that. So you can adjust the load of the supply with your decade. Just be careful in which direction you switch you stuff, you can easily create a short circuit if you set it to 10 kOhm and want to test 100 Ohm and turn down the kOhm dial to zero before setting the 100 Ohm dial.

I use the Danbridge decades quite regularly in my work to test the temperature resistor measurement part of our sensors. If you have a precision decade it's much easier that hooking up different resistors. You can easily test the linearity and measurement range for example.

Another use is to test the low power LEDs we use to see the difference in brightness with varying current. In our designs it's often not feasible to implement a constant current design, so we stick to plain voltage and resistor. To get the right value resistor, these boxes are quite useful.

As for your second question if yours is okay:
[image: calculated the deviation]

It looks mostly okay. Have you zeroed your test leads? In the low ohmic region it looks like you might have the test leads resistance being a factor there (mine are often in the region of 0.3 Ohms).
Other then that only 100 kOhm stand out with -3.8 %.

According to your link, it should be within 2 % and 5 % for the 1 Ohm range. Yours is borderline on the 1 and 10 ohms but pretty good in the rest.

Comment: nope, if I measure Ohms through the leads I get about .4 so that makes sense!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I had a position as a receiving inspector, I used one of these to test out all kinds of electrical components. One of the main ones was these DC/DC converters. I used the varying resistance of the decade box and a couple of multi meters to see if the converters put out as much power as they were supposed to.That one actually looks really cool. I would have been really excited to see it in a thrift shop. Now, as a hobbyist, I can think of several uses for one. Designing an amplifier and wanting to know which resistor works? Try several different settings in the decade box and find out which one. It is not as efficient as using math, but might end up being more fun or more of a learning experience (especially if you blow something up ;).I agree with Arsenal here that some of the values are borderline, but if you are just using it as a hobbyist anyway, you are fine.